# Proving a convex space is connected

Tags: general-topology

A set $C \subset R^n$ is convex if given any $x_1, x_2 \in C$, the line segment connecting $x_1$
and $x_2$ is contained in C. Show that any convex set $C \subset R^n$ must be connected.

I want to prove this by assuming that C is disconnected and finding a contradiction. I know that since C is disconnected this means it has a pair of nonempty open sets A and B which partition it. So then if I choose $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$, the line segment connecting these two points is contained in C. My idea is to show that if the line segment is contained in C then this contradicts A and B both being open. Will this work? I can't find the right way to finish this proof.

Comment: As an alternative, recall that any path-connected space is, in particular, connected.

Comment: That's true but I'm not allowed to use that fact in my answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume a decomposition $C= A \cup B$ exists as you have described.  Define $f:C \to \Bbb R$ via $f(x) = 0~ \forall x \in A$ and $f(x)=1~ \forall x \in B$.  Then $f:C \to \Bbb R$ is continuous.  Define $g:[0, 1] \to C$ via $g(t)=tx_1+(1-t)x_2.$  Then $g$ is continuous, so $f \circ g:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ is also continuous.  But $f \circ g$ must be discontinuous because (among other things) it violates the Intermediate Value Theorem:  $f \circ g(0)=0, f \circ g(1)=1, \forall t \in (0, 1)~ f \circ g(t) \neq \frac{1}{2}.$  That's a contradiction, so there can be no such decomposition of $C$.

**Edited to add:**

To see that $f$ is continuous, choose $x \in C$.  Then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.  Let's assume $x \in A$.  Because $A$ is open, there exists an open ball $U$ around $x$ such that $U \subseteq A$.  Then $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \forall y \in U, |f(y)-f(x)| = 0 \lt \epsilon$, so $f$ is continuous at $x$.  But $x$ is arbitrary, so $f$ is continuous throughout $C$.

Comment: The only part I don't understand here is why you can say that f is continuous.

Comment: A function is continuous if the inverse image of any open set is also open.  (That definition of open works in arbitrary topologies, not just metric spaces.)  Here, the inverse image under $f$ of every open set is $\emptyset, A, B,$ or $C$, all of which are open.

Comment: By the way, thanks for accepting.  Please don't hesitate also to upvote any answers you found useful, not just mine.

Comment: What is $f \circ g(t)$ when $t\in (0,1)$, e.g. $g(1/2)=\frac12 x_1+\frac12 x_2=\ldots$?

Comment: @sunny $f\circ g(\frac 12)=f(p)$, where $p$ is the midway point between $x_1$ and $x_2$.  The point of the proof is that the continuous function $f \circ g$ is always either $0$ or $1$, which isn't possible because of the Intermediate Value Theorem.  When you transition from $A$ to $B$, the function makes a discontinuous jump from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\sup \{t\in [0,1]: tx_2+(1-t)x_1 \in A \}$. Call this $a$. Using the fact that $sx_2+(1-s)x_1 \in A^{c}$ for all $s>a$  conclude that $ax_2+(1-a)x_1 \in B $. Now use the fact that $B$ is open to get the contradiction that $sx_2+(1-s)x_1 \in B$ for $s<a$ and sufficiently close to $a$ contradicting the definition of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We can describe the line segment connecting $x_1$ and $x_2$ by the path $\alpha: [0,1] \to C$, where $\alpha(t) = (1-t)x_1 + tx_2$. Then since $[0,1]$ is connected, and $\alpha$ is continuous, $\alpha([0,1])$ - aka, the line segment connecting these two points - must also be connected. (Hopefully you can use paths, if not path-connectedness!)

Can you see where to go from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you!